# Is it possible to evenly distribute buttons across the width of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` (oriented horizontally) that contains 3 buttons. I want the 3 buttons to have a fixed width and be evenly distributed across the width of the `LinearLayout`.

I can manage this by setting the gravity of the `LinearLayout` to center and then adjusting the padding of the buttons, but this works for a fixed width and won't work for different devices or orientations.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="120dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="120dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="120dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450561/scrollview-issue-in-android-layout-xml

Comment: Look into this [Equal width ImageViews in horizontal LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30660258/782535)

Comment: Anyone here from google User Interface course :3

Comment: you can set weight sum programmatically and make buttons inside for loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611531/android-layout-weight-programmatically

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Expanding on [fedj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470420/is-it-possible-to-evenly-distribute-buttons-across-the-width-of-an-android-linear/3470733#3470733), if you set `layout_width` to `0dp` and set the `layout_weight` for each of the buttons to 1, the available width will be shared equally between the buttons.

Comment: To expand on this, if you don't want the width of the buttons to be 1/3rd of the screen, wrap each button in a LinearLayout and set layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="1" on the 3 LinearLayouts.  Additionally, set the gravity on the LinearLayouts to "center" so the buttons will align in the center of each LinearLayout.

Comment: this is the case for linearlayout only.can any one give any idea for equispacing in relativelayout

Comment: In my case, i use  layout_width="wrap_content" and only with layout_weight="1" works good!

Comment: This is not correct as the OP wants fixed with. See stoefln's answer.

Comment: what about imageview where we need equal padding? cant set weight to imageview as image will be stretched.

Answer (score 269):

If you don't want the buttons to scale, but adjust the spacing between the buttons (equal spacing between all buttons), you can use views with weight="1" which will fill the space between the buttons:

```
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/tars_active" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/videos_active" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>
```

Comment: This is definitely the simplest, lowest overhead method that works (for the case where you want the space between the views to scale, not the views themselves). I'm using it vertically, and so just swapped the width and height values. Thanks.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. You may prefer to use the `Space` view type. Makes things a bit more readable.

Comment: Ryan, yes, that is if you are using API 14+ (as we should).

Comment: Honestly, I thought it won't work when having 4 buttons, but it worked brilliantly with no fuss and runtime measuring. Respect!

Comment: This is better than the one that's accepted as answer currently.

Comment: This code misses the top linear layout. For this to work with an arbitrary number of buttons, you need each button wrapped within spaces. Works beautifully though.

Comment: didn't even know Space was a type of View. Thanks for this simple straightforward solution.

Answer (score 33):

### The modern solution for this is [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:justifyContent="space_around"> <!-- or "space_between", "space_evenly" -->

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:width="120dp" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:width="120dp" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:width="120dp" />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Make sure to import `implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.0'`

`Flexbox` is far more powerful; it is a good complement to `ConstraintLayout`. [This is a great resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn more.

[image: Difference between space_around, space_between, and space_evenly]

Comment: thanks for making me (us) aware of it. Definitely useful. I used "space_around" and the buttons were nicely centered when I had 1 or 3 visible within the FlexBox

Answer (score 31):

You can do this by giving both `View`s a `layout_width` of `0dp` and a `layout_weight` of `1`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="example text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The way android layout_weight works is that:**

- first, it looks to the size that a View would normally take and reserves this space.
- second, if the layout is `match_parent` then it will divide the **space that is left** in the ratio of the `layout_weight`s. Thus if you gave the Views `layout_weight="2"` and `layout_weight="1"`,the resultant ratio will be 2 to 1,that is : the first View will get 2/3 of the space that is left and the other view 1/3.

So that's why if you give `layout_width` a size of `0dp` the first step has no added meaning since both Views are not assigned any space. Then only the second point decides the space each `View` gets, thus giving the `View`s the space you specified according to the ratio!

**To explain why `0dp` causes the space to devide equally by providing an example that shows the opposite:** The code below would result in something different since `example text` now has a width that is greater than `0dp` because it has `wrap_content` instead making the free space left to divide less than 100% because the text takes space. The result will be that they do get 50% of the free space left but the text already took some space so the `TextView` will have **well over 50%** of the total space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="example text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 24):

You may use it with  like the following.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that's sweeet!! I never heard of `Space` until just now

Answer (score 14):

You should take a look to android:layout_weight attribute

Comment: It was my understanding that the layout_weight attribute will stretch the size of the button to fill the layout.  I want to keep the size of the buttons constant and just increase the padding between the buttons.

Comment: Ah ! I don't really know the best way to do it. Perhaps enclosing each button in layout. The 3 layout with layout_weight attribute and the button centered in the layout. But I really don't know if it is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 13):

Well, if you have exactly 3 buttons and if it is ok (or even planned) that the outer buttons are aligned to the left and right side then you might want to try a RelativeLayout which is less overhead (in many situations).

You can use `layout_alignParentBottom` to align all buttons with the bottom of the layout. Use `layout_alignParentLeft and Right` for the outer buttons and `layout_centerHorizontal` for the middle button.

That will work well on different orientations and screen sizes.

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't work if you have more than three buttons.

Comment: Exactly. You'd have to use a LinearLayout or RadioGroup (if applicable) instead.

Answer (score 8):

You should use an `android:weightSum` attribute linear layout. Give linear layout a weightSum equal to the number of Buttons inside the layout, then set `android:layout_weight="1"` and set width of the button `android:layout_width="0dp"`
further, you can style the layout using paddings and layout margins.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="3">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="120dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" 
        />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="120dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="120dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In order to do it dynamically

```
void initiate(Context context){
    LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(context);

    parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    parent.setWeightSum(3);
    parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    AppCompatButton button1 = new AppCompatButton(context);
    button1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0 ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));

    AppCompatButton button2 = new AppCompatButton(context);
    button2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0 ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));

    AppCompatButton button3 = new AppCompatButton(context);
    button3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0 ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
    
    parent.addView(button1);
    parent.addView(button2);
    parent.addView(button3);

}
```

Comment: again i want it dynamically

Answer (score 6):

In `linearLayout` Instead of giving weight to `Button` itself , set the weight to `<Space>` View this won't stretch the `Button`.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.955">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/captureButton"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_round_camera_24" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraChangerBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_round_switch_camera_24" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

as I am using 4 `<Space>` I set the `android:weightSum="4"` In `linear layout` also this is the result ::

[image: layout preview]

Answer (score 4):

For evenly spacing out two buttons in a horizontal linear layout, I used 3 LinearLayout objects to act as spaces which are going to be automatically resized. I positioned these LinearLayout objects as follow:

[] Button1 [] Button2 []

([] represents a LinearLayout object used for spacing)

then I set each of these [] LinearLayout objects' weights to 1, and I get evenly spaced out buttons.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

i created a custom View [DistributeLayout](https://gist.github.com/martyglaubitz/c6e6cc8248bc9978274c) to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use LinearLayout's weightSum attribute.

Adding the tag
`android:weightSum="3"` to your LinearLayout's xml declaration and then `android:layout_weight="1"` to your Buttons will result in the 3 buttons being evenly distributed.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved assigning **[`weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html?hl=es-419#attr_android:layout_weight)** to every button added inside the container, very important to define horizontal orientation :

```
    int buttons = 5;

    RadioGroup rgp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    rgp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for (int i = 1; i <= buttons; i++) {
        RadioButton rbn = new RadioButton(this);         
        rbn.setId(1 + 1000);
        rbn.setText("RadioButton" + i);
        //Adding weight
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        rbn.setLayoutParams(params);
        rgp.addView(rbn);
    }
```

so we can get this in our device as a result:

[image]

even if we rotate our device the **[`weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html?hl=es-419#attr_android:layout_weight)** defined in each button can distribuite the elemenents uniformally along the container:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Best approach is to use `TableLayout` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and in columns use `android:layout_weight="1"` for all columns.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers using layout_didn't work for me, but the following did.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks on screen,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Above all answers are right but In a case you need visible and gone features then this pragmatically method will work well

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>



 float width=CommonUtills.getScreenWidth(activity);
            int cardWidth=(int)CommonUtills.convertDpToPixel (((width)/3),activity);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

btnOne.setLayoutParams(params);
btnTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
btnThree.setLayoutParams(params);

public class CommonUtills {
public static float getScreenWidth(Context context) {
        float width = (float) 360.0;
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        return width;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Equally weighted children](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics#Weight)

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of
>   space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to
>   "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view
>   to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight
>   of each view to "1".

In order for this to work in the `LinearLayout` view group the attribute values for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` need to be equal to `"match_parent"`...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this . it's so easy to understand :
by https://developer.android

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:text="Tom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Tim"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Todd"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Tom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Tim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Todd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In circle, Tom, Tim, and Todd get assumed to be 3 centimeters. If you want it to be touch down screen, put it as Tom and Tim getting assumed to be 1 centimeter, which means they combine virtual but its 2D plane is at the bottom. This is displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way, (but not the best), is to add a TextView with empty text attribute, like this

```
android:text=""
```

the background color must be the same at the LinearLayout, then you could use the padding property, like this

```
android:paddingBottom="250dp"
```

or whatever you need.
[Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDmSp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 3 buttons to have a fixed width and be evenly distributed across the width of the layout... why not use constraintLayout?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="120dip"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnTwo">
            
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="120dip"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnThree"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnOne"></Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="120dip"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnTwo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
            
        </Button>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I want through java though, which is dynamic and not through xml

Comment: then you might need a Horizontal RecyclerView:
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-dynamic-horizontal-recyclerview-in-android-using-firebase-firestore/
or Perhaps if you need a list with different components, just make an heterogeneous recyclerView: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogeneous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Width and be are evenly distributed across the width of the layout. Why not use constraintLayout?

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <Button android:id="@+id/btnOne" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:width="120dip"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnTwo">
 </Button> 

 <Button android:id="@+id/btnTwo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:width="120dip" 
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnThree"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnOne"></Button> <Button 
  android:id="@+id/btnThree" android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:width="120dip" 
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnTwo" 
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"> 
 </Button>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to nest buttons inside a constraint layout and space them equaly this way. Make sure to set the constraints properly, so the buttons will be spaced equaly in the layout.

Works even if you have a LinearLayout as root.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="asdf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/shareButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="sdsfa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/deleteButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/deleteButton" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:text="Tom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Tim"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Todd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```