# android Layout weight programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i have hard-coded the layout_weight on layout xml.but now i want to give the layout_weight and weightSum from java code.

How we do that from our class?

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="25" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#F51215"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:text="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="#1AC92B"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:text="20" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
//set as like this below for different view set different float value.

myview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,5f));
```

Comment: Note that unlike in XML, you should NOT set the height or width to 0 as the Layout will simply not appear otherwise.

Comment: @TheIT May be its changed now. Setting width zero worked.

Answer (score 44):

Something like this:

```
               ......
               LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(YOUR_LAYOT_ID);
               layout.setWeightSum(25f);
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams(); //or create new LayoutParams... 

               lParams.weight = 0.5f;
               .......
               someView.setLayoutParams(lParams);
               .......
```

Comment: I cannot do this for someView being a TextView. Any other solution?

Comment: @NarayanaJ, are you sure? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setWeightSum(float)

Comment: @VyacheslavShilkin, thanks for pointing out. I seem to have lost the context of why I was trying this, but Studio threw an error when I put that method in my `Activity`, for some reason, leading me to believe the method was deprecated. Apparently, that method is very much in the API. Sorry for the hasty comment, shall I delete it? Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

I just wanted to add an example of how to use the weightsum with e.g a TableRow with TextViews inside:

```
           TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
           TableRow.LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10f);
           row.setLayoutParams(params1);
           row.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
           row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);

           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
           TableRow.LayoutParams params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 6f);
           tv.setLayoutParams(params2);
           tv.setTextSize(30);
           tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

           TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
           TableRow.LayoutParams params3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2f);
           tv2.setLayoutParams(params3);
           tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

           TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
           TableRow.LayoutParams params4 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2f);
           tv3.setLayoutParams(params4);
           tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
```

Produces the TableRow underneath. The parent whose weightsum is 10, and the children's widths are then equal to 60%, 20% and 20% of the width. The height is here determined by the TextView, tv, which has a height of 30. Hope it helps someone. :-)

[image: text]

Answer (score 7):

**If You want to change parent weight programmatically and it's child property as it is then use below**

Here's how you set it.

```
 LinearLayout yourLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
 yourLayout.setWeightSum(0.6f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically Generate TextView with Weight using LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout lin_hoizontal = new LinearLayout(context);
lin_hoizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lin_hoizontal.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10f));
lin_hoizontal.setPadding((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_8), (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_2), (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_8), (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_2));

android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_label = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2.5f);
TextView txt_label = new TextView(context);
txt_label.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.listing_header_txt_color));//your text color
txt_label.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_13));
txt_label.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL));
txt_label.setLayoutParams(params_label);
txt_label.setPadding(0, 0, (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_2), 0);
txt_label.setText("Label");


android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_value = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 7.5f);
TextView txt_value = new TextView(context);
txt_value.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.listing_header_txt_color));
txt_value.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_13));
txt_value.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
txt_value.setLayoutParams(params_value);
txt_value.setPadding((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_2), 0, 0, 0);
txt_value.setText("Value");

lin_hoizontal.addView(txt_label);
lin_hoizontal.addView(txt_value);
lin_hoizontal.addView(lin_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Ajii's answer or:

```
((LinearLayout)view).setWeightSum(n);
```

and for individual view weight:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams()).weight = n;
```

- of course you can do.. `LinearLayout view = findViewById(R.id.view_name);`

  (and drop the dynamic casting (LinearLayout))
- or substitute...……….. `findViewById(R.id.view_name)` for view above.

These both worked for me.
And if you want value in dimens file:

```
<item name="new_weight" format="float" type="dimen">(your number)</item>
```

and: `float n = getResources().getFloat(R.dimen.new_weight);`

I'm sure you already know most of this but... I was a newbie once and I always appreciated the extra descriptions.