# Linear layout match parent or weight doesn't work in Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-layout-weight, android-layoutparams

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.now.sexyfacechanger.Activity_PhotoOrGallery">

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity__photo_or_gallery" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_gallery"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the view in android studio design, the linear layout displayed does match the parent:

[image]

But the output:

[image]

The linear layout doesn't match parent or I suspect the layout_weight applied to the two floating buttons doesn't work in Coordinator layout.

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`

Comment: @SelçukCihan just tried, doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you also change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the linear layout?

Comment: @SelçukCihan thanks, now the two fabs are at bottom and center horizontal. But my desired view is to split the view in to half and each fab center horizontal in each half. Would like to know the cause and the solution of this problem.

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470420/is-it-possible-to-evenly-distribute-buttons-across-the-width-of-an-android-linea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `FloatingActionButton` can only have a fixed size.

You can add some space between them.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Space    
        android:layout_weight="1"     
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
    <Space    
        android:layout_weight="2"     
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
    <Space    
        android:layout_weight="1"     
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe if you will use LinearLayout it can help you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="@dimen/space_small_xs"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_small_l"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_small_l">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_white_left"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/text_subscribe_light"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_small_l"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_small_l">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_white_right"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/text_subscribe_light"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It will look like this:

[image]