# layout_weight doesn't take effect

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to split the **vertical** space between views evenly using `layout_weight` but from some reason it doesn't work. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470420/is-it-possible-to-evenly-distribute-buttons-across-the-width-of-an-android-linea) and still the views's spaces aren't effected by that. What am I doing wrong?

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </Space>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </Space>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </Space>

                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </Space>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: 
if image is not shown (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQaLm.png)
[[image: graphic explanation]

Comment: can you put your screen shot which you want to develop?

Comment: Please explain further what you're trying to accomplish, and what exactly isn't working as expected. From what I can tell from your description, that layout will do what you want.

Comment: That's what that layout will do. You have one space at the top, a space between each `View`, and they will all be equal height. To check, you can temporarily change the `<Space>`s to `<View>`s, set their `layout_width`s to `match_parent`, and give them `background` colors. Btw, I think you mean vertical space.

Comment: I have tried your code in xml file and don't see any problems. The items seem to be spaced equally. What needs to be solved?

Comment: So, your specific problem is that it's not taking up the entire screen vertically?

Answer (score -1):

Just add below line to your linearlayout:

```
android:weightSum="4"
```