# Spinner with scrollbar

Tags: android, spinner

I have a simple spinner with 20 items in it. A scrollbar for same spinner appears by default when  launching the application the first time. And afterwards it fades out immediatly. So to select last item in spinner I have to use arrow keys on keyboard.

One more problem with spinner:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

This also doesn't work. I can't see the selector on top.

Comment: Open a new question for your second question.

Answer (score 1):

[Customspinner](http://code.google.com/p/customspinner/)
[scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450561/scrollview-issue-in-android-layout-xml)
[example](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/)
[example](http://www.anddev.org/general-f3/android-checkbox-t15923.html)
 [try this also](http://pastebin.com/ivKNKXXR)

this may helps you