# ScrollView scrolls, but doesn't displays its content completely

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-scrollview

I have divided my layout in 2 scrollviews by using this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:background="@drawable/ashokb"
    android:layout_weight="4" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:background="@drawable/flagc">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_share" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textColor="#000000" 

            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:background="@drawable/ashokb"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"       
            android:text="Medium Text"
               android:textColor="#000000"      
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This displays in GraphicalLayout like this[image]

In device & emulators the view becomes correct in dialog as I want :[image]

**Problem:** If the text in textview is small then  the 1st scrollview behaves normal as expected, but if the text in texview is large then the complete text is not visible even after scrolling compltely, Instead it shows blank at the end of the scroll. As shown in this video

http://youtu.be/fIqzTQ8neGs

See in the last clicked item, The first scrollview is not displaying its contents completely.

I hope you get this problem clear.

Any solution for that ?

Comment: why two scrollviews .put all in single scrollview. it may work

Comment: No, I dont want that, I want the contents in the scrollview must always be visible at the top, & if its content(i.e text) become larger then it can be viewed by scrolling that particular area(scrollview1)

Comment: set wrap_content to the value height at the first scrollview and tell me how it works..

Comment: @Nemka It didnt worked

Comment: Ok,try to put android:paddingTop="20dp" in the first linearLayout after the first scrollview to see..

Comment: @Nemka still the same problem

Comment: Why u put width="0px" may i know reason for it??

Comment: Assigh `weightSum` to your topmost `LinearLayout` like `android:weightSum="5"`.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450561/scrollview-issue-in-android-layout-xml, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470420/is-it-possible-to-evenly-distribute-buttons-across-the-width-of-an-android-linea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you have many unnecessary attributes set in your layout file. But your issue is caused by `android:layout_gravity` attribute set on first `LinearLayout` in your top `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Removing `android:layout_gravity="center"` will resolve your issue with cropped content inside this `ScrollView`.

---

**By the way**: If the content inside of it is smaller than `ScrollView` and you want to center it inside you should use different approach. You don't want to center child directly inside `ScrollView` but you should fill the `ScrollView` with it's only child and center the content inside this child. Normally you would set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on this `LinearLayout` and `android:gravity="center"`. But in `ScrollView` you cannot use such approach - the height of `ScrollView` direct child should always be `wrap_content` and setting it to `match_parent` wont work. There is however an attribute in `ScrollView` to allow such behavior, it's called [setFillViewport(boolean fillViewport)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setFillViewport(boolean)) and you should set it to true, like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
```

Apart from that following lines in `ScrollView` dont make any sense. It basically sets a gravity os this `ScrollView` to `center`, but since it matches the size of it's parent - it cannot be positioned in a center.

```
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

---

BTW. Second `ScrollView` shouldn't have a `android:layout_height` set to `wrap_content`. Please change it to `match_parent`.

Also you should really try to simplify your layout and number of attributes (especially all the "gravities":)

Comment: Thanks maciej , I had this Issue earlier but I forgotted how do I solved it, & you made me remember! also Thanks for the knowledge you gave, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139656/scrollview-doesnt-display-its-content-properly-in-lower-versions-of-android

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be fixed elegantly by using the Parallax effect. Have a look at it - you can check this
 [Github project](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)

You can get the Demo App from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nirhart.parallaxscrollexample)

Comment: Thank you, Parallax is a lil different to what I have implemeted & also its a good library

Answer (score 0):

I have used your xml code and changed it by eliminating your **layout_gravity="center"** attributes. Now it works. Apart from the backgrounds you can use xml code given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#ec2345">

<RelativeLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0px"
android:background="#ec1234"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 

        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0px" 
  android:layout_weight="1" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"       
        android:text="Medium Text"
           android:textColor="#000000"      
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         />

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139656/scrollview-doesnt-display-its-content-properly-in-lower-versions-of-android