# ScrollView doesn't display its content properly in lower versions of android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview, android-2.3-gingerbread

You can see my scrollview being displayed the same in jellybean, & kitkat, very awesome:

[image: one] [image]

But I am shocked to see the same thing in lower versions like 2.2, 2.3.3

[image] [image]

It seems that it display some portion of text attached to upper & bottom portion of screen.

BTW, The lines in middle are just the textviews with gray background .

You can see my xml code, sorry its a little long code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/stars"
android:padding="5dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
>


<LinearLayout


android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ems="10"
     android:textColor="#fff"
     android:hint="Type your Full Name here"
     android:inputType="textPersonName"
     android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz " >

     <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#330000"
     android:onClick="showresult"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:alpha=".8"
     android:text="Show My Fortune" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView13"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:baselineAligned="false">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="20dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="18sp"
              />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="18sp" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView3"
             android:layout_width="20dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="18sp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="18sp" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_weight="1"  >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView5"
             android:layout_width="20dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="18sp"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView6"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="18sp" />
     </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView7"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height=".5dp"

     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView8"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView9"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView14"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:gravity="right"

         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView10"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView15"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:textColor="#ffffff"

         android:gravity="right"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView11"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView16"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:textColor="#ffffff"

         android:gravity="right"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView12"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height=".5dp"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView17"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" 
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView18"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="right"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView19"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView20"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#ff0000"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView21"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:gravity="right"
         android:textColor="#ff0000"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView27"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView22"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffff00"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView23"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ff0000"
         android:gravity="right"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView28"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView24"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:textColor="#ffff00"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView25"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="right"
         android:textColor="#ff0000"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView29"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView26"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffff00"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also in GraphicalLayout is shows this warning :[image]

I hope I explained my problem clearly !

Looking for a answer,

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE**: After @semsamot answer the above warning was disappeared, but the problem is still not solved.

Sorry, my above code was too long but I have another layout in my app displaying the same problem

Consider this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/stars"
tools:context="com.vivekwarde.numerologyfortune.MyLuckyNumber"
>
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
            android:text="Birthdate ?"
            android:background="#4c0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I display this layout simply it displays as expected in jelly bean & kitkat like this[image]

But see this output in 2.2 & 2.3.3
[image]

Why the text in `TextView` does not display properly as expected. ?

Comment: Do you get this behavior on a particular device?

Comment: Yes this behaviour is there in spice mi-270 (v2.2), also I see this behaviour in emulators 2.2 & 2.3.3 !

Comment: Can you try with this: `<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical" >`

Comment: @SimonMarquis The same problem exists though I tried what u said !

Comment: It could be that the button is overlaps the textarea. If i was you i would check if that is the case

Comment: Ya i thought the same but what can i do

Comment: Are you aware of the current share of android versions? https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net 2.2 is 0.7%, 2.3 is 13.6% and of course they get less every day. Just saying as you might decide it's not worth the effort or worry to support a diminishing percentage, currently 14.3%.

Comment: Just using the percentage in the opposite direction, 14.3% means a relevant amount of users for some of us.

Comment: Issue filed to android here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76453

Answer (score 4):

Don't use float values that lower than 1 in this format: ".x"
Instead use this format: "0.x"

If you change those values you see the warnings disappear!

**Note:**
Also note that "alpha" attribute introduced in API Level 11 so it will not work in lower API(s).

Comment: After following your answer, warnings were disappeared, I am facing the same problem in lower versions ! Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll work but u should try it once.

instead of using `android:layout_height="60dp"` use `maxHeight` and `minHeight` with same value 60dp as ur case .I think it will solve your problem.And also fill some background color to see whats wrong with the soln.

Comment: U mean to say inside button?

Comment: Its giving me  java.lang.RuntimeException button should have layout_height attribute

Comment: You must have layout_height attrib but having value wrap content.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: can you share any file or demo using drive or dropbox on which we can add some.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use wrap_content for the ScrollView. The ScrollView should have a concrete size which is relate with the screen size, not the content. The LinearLayout inside it should keep the wrap_content. In both your examples, you should use match_parent for the ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

don`t use .5dp while setting height or width

> ```
> <TextView
>  android:id="@+id/textView7"
>  android:layout_width="match_parent"
>  android:layout_height=".5dp"  //  **modify** this to android:layout_height="1dp"
>  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
> ```

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView12"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height=".5dp"  //  **modify** this to android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

Using this you can remove this error **requestfocus does not set the required layout_height attribute** and also might be you can solve your issue also

Comment: This answer was already posted, & BTW the problem is something else